# Using Profiles in Automapper to map the same types with different logic with DI support for CustomValue Resolvers

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

I am  trying to use automapper in .net core 1.0.1 application to map types with different logic based on profiles. I have some custom resolvers as well. I am not able to get the DI support in custom resolvers. Here is my code to create mappers.

```cs
private IMapper CreateMapper(string srcFormName)
{
    switch (srcFormName)
    {
        case "app1":
            {
                var configuration1 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile<App1Profile>();
                });
                 return configuration1.CreateMapper();
            }
        case "app2":
            {
                var configuration2 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile<App2Profile>();
                });
                return configuration2.CreateMapper();
            }
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

I am using the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/2.0.1 and the below line has been added to Startup.cs

```cs
 services.AddAutoMapper();
```

I need a custom resolver like below

```cs
public class NameResolver : IValueResolver<MyType1, MyType2, string>
{
    private IContextInfo _contextInfo;

    //public NameResolver()
    //{

    //}

    public NameResolver(IContextInfo contextInfo)
    {
        _contextInfo = contextInfo;
    }

    public string Resolve(ApplicationForm source, StpApplication destination,
        string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        _contextInfo.RulesExecuted.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        return source.FirstName + " " + source.MiddleName + " " + source.LastName;
    }
}
```

But when I try to map, I am getting an exception like parameterless constructor is not present(on my resolver) and fails to map. I believe this could be because of creating my own mapper configuration, but then I don't know to work with multiple profiles without creating own configuration. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

When using the extension from [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) to integrate it with native IoC from .NET Core, you don't need to apply a mapper-configuration yourself.

Just pass the assemblies to the function

```
services.AddAutoMapper(myAssembliesContainingAutoMapperTypes);
```

If the types are in the sameproject as your Startup-Class do it like this

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
```

Now it will register [profiles, valueresolver and so on automatically](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/191acb94a6c21163339d5d0b81bb0f2c19efab2b/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L74).
It also has an extension method to pass the mapper configuration to it. This will then be used and just expanded.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(config => { ... }, typeof(Startup).Assembly);
```

If you don't pass the assemblies containing your resolvers and other automapper types, you can also manually register your resolvers.

```
services.AddTransiert(typeof(NameResolver));
```

First approach is better and recommended, you will never ever register stuff yourself. That's why this library was built. Just pass the assemblies containing your types :)

Comment: Hope you understood my requirement too. In this style, how can I specify a profile for mapping. Creating own configuration was the only way I know. Please let me know, if there is some other way.

Comment: Yes, I told you, you can pass a mapper configuration to the the extension method. Read good. You could also provide more informations about why you need to define which profiles should be used. Maybe it is a design flaw.

Comment: If I can determine only at runtime which mapping profile needs to run, I am not sure how to approach

Comment: You can pass the configuration to the method, just look at the example I provided and try to dig into the code on github to understand what is happening.